# Outlook behaving strangely - opens emails without my control

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have MS Office 2007 running under Vista and this morning Outlook started behaving strangely.

I had pointed to Inbox and was working on a different computer when I noticed the screen showing a different folder even though I hadn't touched the mouse.

This has occurred a couple of times plus an email was maximized which I think can only be done by double clicking and I definitely didn't touch the mouse.

I fear I've had my computer hijacked so I disconnected from my router and I'm currently running a full system scan with both Windows Defended and AVG but wondered if this is something that has been seen before.

Many thanks in advance for any help

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that, for example, you left your PC and the inbox was selected, you then turned and folder1 was selected and an email was open? Do you use something like LogMeIn, Go To My PC or teamviewer?

Comment: and when the email was maximized, was this a new email to send, or an email you had received?

Comment: Hi Dave - thanks for responding.

Yes - I left the computer showing the inbox and when I returned it was showing another folder.

The email that was maximized was one that I had received.

I don't use Go To My PC or anything else like that and never access it remotely.